# Choosing a Paypal Service

Tags: php, api, laravel, paypal, invoice

I am new in Laravel and my client wants me to integrate one of he Paypal services.
There's so many services in Paypal and i don't know where to start.Please see the image below. I think this is not a express checkout where i usually use because the user only fill up a form with "order number" and "amount" field and then redirected to this Paypal interface. Please see this link of the image :

http://maverickpreviews.com/programming/royalgeelong/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Paypal-Services.png

Can anyone describe what is the exact paypal service is that?

This is the current form: https://www.impressink.com/payment.php

This is what i tried in my Paypal Express Checkout controller

> $stringwithmethodalready = '&Amt=79.95&ReturnUrl='.$returnURL
>         .'&CANCELURL='.$cancelURL       .'&PAYMENTACTION='.$paymentType
>         .'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.$currencyID
>         .'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM='.$testinvoice
>         .'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.$testotal
>         .'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT='.$thetax
>         .'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT='.$theshipping
>         .'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT='.$thehandling
>         .'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT='.$theshipdis
>         .'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT='.$theinsurance
>         .'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.$testotal.
>         '&ALLOWNOTE=1&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole';

Comment: it looks like a basic paypal form https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/

Comment: I have edited the post. I put the form link so that you can see the current form. I can't see any invoice parameters in that document you've given

Answer (score 1):

From the image it could be either express checkout or a Paypal payment standard integration.The invoice parameter is `invoice` for Paypal payment standard and `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM` for express checkout.

- PayPal button Parameter list [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).
- PayPal Express checkout Parameter list [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/).

This form https://www.impressink.com/payment.php is using Website Payment Standard Integration.

Foe EC, a sample SetExpressCheckout with Invoice,line item details would be:

```
VERSION = 109.0
METHOD = SetExpressCheckout
RETURNURL = http://www.google.com
CANCELURL = http://www.google.com
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION= Sale
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=1 Decaf Kona Blend Coffee  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=623083  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Size: 8.8-oz 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=9.95  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1

PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM = 12345
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=9.95
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=9.95
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
```

When I used the above request, I get this
[image]

Comment: Please correct me, i will use express checkout, then i have a loop of items. where should i put the `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM` ? Do i have to put the invoice number and the price inside the loop of item like this? `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME_0=1234&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT_0=12` ? Sorry, You are helping a newbie here.

Comment: @RomnickSusa check my updated answer and yes if you have multiple items, you can have it in a loop

Comment: Thank you for your help, i tried your answer but i am getting an empty order summary in paypal.

Comment: it should work unless your request is incorrect. If you can provide the EC-token, I shall look into and you are missing mandatory parameters for displaying order summary such as L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0,L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0

Comment: Actually i intentionally removed the `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0` to `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0` because i don't have product to pass through. The form only had a "invoice number" field and the "amount" field so i don't have idea what to pass in express checkout. When i tried the whole  parameter using your suggestion. I got the same result as yours.

Comment: if you want to display the order summary in express checkout integration you will need to pass the line item details such as L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the param item_number works for you:

```
<input type="text" name="item_number" value="'.$order_id.'">
```

Checkout the rest of params [Paypal standar params](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/)